# Typesetting LaTeX fraction terms to be larger in an equation

Tags: latex, formula, equation, mathematical-typesetting

I have the following formula in LaTeX, based on [Fisher's Exact Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test). (**NOTE**: requires the use of the `amsmath` package for `\binom`.)

```
\begin{equation}
    P(i,j) = \sum_{x=|N(V_i) \cap V_j|}^{\min\{|V_j|, |N(V_i)|}
    \frac{ \binom{|V_j|}{x} \binom{|V - V_j|}{|N(V_i)| - x}}
    {\binom{|V|}{|N(V_i)|}}
\end{equation}
```

This renders the fraction portion with very small, difficult to read text:

[image: equation with small text in fraction]

I would like my text more readable, as in the following example:

[image: equation with readable text in fraction]
<sub>(source: [plosone.org](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0005313.e002&representation=PNG))</sub>

What trickery can I use to get LaTeX to render my equation similarly?

Comment: The second example is from Word's Equation Editor, isn't it?

Comment: @Charles I'm not sure how it was generated, but it appears in the following article in PLoS One: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0005313

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
\begin{equation}
    P(i,j) = \sum_{x=|N(V_i) \cap V_j|}^{\min\{|V_j|, |N(V_i)|} 
    \frac{\displaystyle \binom{|V_j|}{x} \binom{|V - V_j|}{|N(V_i)| - x}}
    {\displaystyle \binom{|V|}{|N(V_i)|}}   
\end{equation}
```

[image: Formatted equation]

---

Thought it might be good to add a reference:

A Guide to LaTeX2e, Kopka & Daly, 1995
Section 5.5 Fine-Tuning Mathematics
5.5.2 Selecting font size in formulas

In my edition, it's on pp 141-142, but this is out of stock on Amazon. The nearest Internet pointer I can find just now is [here](http://www.bluesky.com/bookshelf/guidetolatex/gl.html)

Answer (score 11):

For fraction you can also use continued fraction `\cfrac` in combination with `\left` and `\right`.

Take a look [here](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsldoc.pdf/0).

Comment: I would consider `cfrac` to be the most correct answer.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @PaulWintz: fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one idea.

In Preamble:

```
\def\mathLarge#1{\mbox{\LARGE $#1$}}
```

Then update your equation to:

```
\begin{equation}
    P(i,j) = \sum_{x=|N(V_i) \cap V_j|}^{\min\{|V_j|, |N(V_i)|}  
    \mathLarge{
        \frac{ \binom{|V_j|}{x} \binom{|V - V_j|}{|N(V_i)| - x}}
        {\binom{|V|}{|N(V_i)|}}
    }
\end{equation}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Very nice alternative, with the added bonus of having greater control over the size of the text in the fraction.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines define three fraction commands with sizes intermediate between \displaystyle and \textstyle, in order of decreasing size:

```
\newcommand{\sdfrac}[2]{\mbox{\small$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}}
\newcommand{\fdfrac}[2]{\mbox{\footnotesize$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}}
\newcommand{\ltfrac}[2]{\mbox{\large$\frac{#1}{#2}$}}
```

See [**this page**](http://www.grputland.com/2015/02/fine-control-over-sizes-of-fractions-in-latex.html) if further explanation is needed.