# Multiple lines in a cell of a table

Tags: latex

I have a table as shown in this figure:

[image]

The LaTeX code for the table is:

```
\begin{table}  
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }  
  \hline  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{../0_1.eps} & 1.10 2.20 3.30 4.40 \\  
  \hline   
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

I would like to make the four numbers appear in different lines inside the second cell, in order to reduce its width. I wonder how to do it?

---

EDIT:

I tried \linebreak,

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{../0_1.eps} & 1.10 \linebreak 2.20 \linebreak 3.30 \linebreak 4.40 \\
```

But the result is the same as before i.e. without \linebreak.

---

EDIT:

I just tried what Rob suggested. But the result is not compact, because my intention is to reduce the size of the table. See the figure below:

[image]

Comment: What's that app you're using to preview this stuff? That's pretty neat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
\begin{table}   
\def\baselinestretch {}\selectfont %
% \baselineskip = 14.4pt\relax %% Uncomment this if the result is not compact.
\begin{tabular}{ | c | p{2cm} | }   
  \hline   
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{../0_1.eps}}$ & 
    $\vcenter{\strut 1.10\par 2.20\par 3.30\par 4.40\strut}$ \\   
  \hline    
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using a p column with \par to indicate line breaks.

```
\begin{table}  
\begin{tabular}{ | c | p{2cm} | }  
  \hline  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{../0_1.eps} & 1.10\par 2.20\par 3.30\par 4.40 \\  
  \hline   
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob! But it makes no change.

Comment: I forgot to use  p{2cm}. But now I have it, the result is not compact as my intention is to reduce the size of the table.

Comment: So reduce \parskip. Inside the table environment, set \parskip=0cm and it will take out those vertical spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mathmode in the last cell: `${1.10 \atop 2.20 } \atop {3.30 \atop 4.40}$`.

That will be nice and small...

If you want it bigger, cf. [Typesetting fraction terms to be larger in an equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660044/typesetting-latex-fraction-terms-to-be-larger-in-an-equation/2661566#2661566).

Answer (score 3):

I would look into using the **multirow** package.  Details on spanning multiple columns/rows are [**here**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning).

Answer (score 1):

\linebreak ? sometimes works for me in tables and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: i just set a table using tabular and a table environment with the book class and miktex, and \linebreak worked for me. :P it also cross compiled with texlive on debian.

Answer (score 1):

Minipage might accomplish this.

```
\begin{minipage}{3in}
% escape the weirdness of tabular with your own mini page
1.10 \\ 2.20 \\ 3.30 \\ 4.40
\end{minipage}
```

You may also want a `\strut` on the first and last lines, to prevent it abutting any tabular borders.