# Latex: How to cells in tables which wrap, but can still be copied as a single line

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to create a table over inputs to a tool which requires the entire input to be on a single line.

My question is similar to [Latex: How to code tables with multi-line cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895780/latex-how-to-code-tables-with-multi-line-cells) in that I want the long lines to wrap.
The problem is that when I copy the text from the PDF using Acrobat Reader it does not copy the lines as a single.
If I copy the first multi-line cell in the example I get

```
Betty Botter Bought a Bit of Butter
but the Butter's Bitter
```

My goal is to get it as a single line.

```
Betty Botter Bought a Bit of Butter but the Butter's Bitter
```

Is there a way to make it wrap the text while copying the wrapped line as a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what your issue is.  Whether your editor and/or Acrobat coies the text as a single line is an issue unrelated to LaTeX.  That is, LaTeX doesn't care whether the text is in a single line or whether it's broken into multiple lines, the output is the same, at least when using the column width specification in the answer to the question you linked.

You might get a better response to your question if you clarify why you don't want the text to be copied in multiple lines.  Is it making some difference in the output (e.g., wrapping at an incorrect spot)?  Some sample code that shows the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it was unrelated to LaTeX.
It wraps correctly. The problem was purely in the copying from Acrobat to another program.