# Resize threepartable for beamer

Tags: resize, latex, beamer

I would like to use the `resize` function from the`graphicx` package to fit a large `threeparttable` into a beamer presentation, however I can't seem to get code from examples that you use tabular environments to work. Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{graphicx,threeparttable,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[h!] \small
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics} \label{tab:descriptivestats}}
    \begin{tabular}{  p{3.5cm} p{1.0cm} p{1.0cm}  p{1.0cm} p{1.0cm} p{1.0cm}}
    \hline
\textbf{Var} & \textbf{Min} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{SD} & \textit{N} \\ 
    \hline
  \hline
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
   XYZ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
  \hline
  \hline
\end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
     \item \textbf{Note:}  XYZ 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to fit, using `resize` or another command?

Comment: Hi! If the answer below was a valid solution for you, mark it as accepted. Otherwise post some further details in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

One first possible solution is to use `\tiny` instead of `\small`: it makes the job in this specific case, despite it may be puzzling to manage if you have more than one such matrices in your document.

The second way ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727092/resize-matrix-in-latex-beamer/2727305#2727305)) is probably more appropriate and systematic:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,threeparttable,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \resizebox{.75\textwidth}{!}{%% begins here
      \begin{threeparttable}

        %% contents of threeparttable

      \end{threeparttable}
    }%% ends here
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```